Random bell sound notification in Ubuntu 22.04
There's a random bell sound notification that goes off, but the only app that made that noise is clocks, which I uninstall, but the sound goes off several times in a few seconds and then goes mute. What's going on?

Settings -> Sound -> Volume Levels Click on the speaker icon or move the slider back to reduce the volume if you still want the alert anyway.

